# Basic user input and validation

Tags: python-3.x

```
#Below is a welcome message to the user. 
print ("Welcome to Smiths Cleaners, offering the best dry-cleaning 
service around!\n")
#Statement to determine if the customers input name is valid
while True:
name=input("What is the customers name? ").lower()
if name.isalpha() or name.split():
    break
print ("invalid input")
print ("\nBelow is the price table for the services available for", name.capitalize() )
```

I am trying to do it so that if the user inputs anything without a capital beginning, it will change the confirmation of the name with a capital however the major issue which i am having is to show the error if the user inputs a number or character (, or : etc)

Comment: Please format the code in your post properly. Like this, we can‘t know which statements are supposed to be grouped together inside or after the while loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others in the comments have suggest, it would help both you and us if you formatted your code properly.

```
while True:
    name = input("What is the customer's name? ").lower()
    if name.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

Now if I understand your question you want to validate that the first letter of the customer's name is capitalized? Then calling `lower` before that validation ensures that all letters are lower case.

In this block you can validate that the name `isalpha` and then check that the first character of the string `isupper`.

```
while True:
    name = input("What is the customer's name? ")
    if name.isalpha() and name[0].isupper():
        break
    else:
        # Handle the invalid input (i.e. replace the first
        # character with valid input, ensure that the rest of 
        # subsequent letters are lowercased).
        print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: Yeah that really helps! Thank you very much, i understand where i went wrong now :)

Comment: Glad to help @Lauren.M